# org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

first i am sorry for my english i am not a native speaker.

I have a android app in which i try to parse an xml file which is anywhere on the phone(is selected via a filechooser). I get from the filechooser a path like this: /storage/emulated/0/file.xml

this is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kartenset>
<row thema="Test"><id>22</id><id_thema>14</id_thema><frage>Frage 1</frage><frage_bild/><antwort_text>Frage 1 Antowrt</antwort_text><antwort_bild/></row>
<row thema="Testfdd"><id>23</id><id_thema>14</id_thema><frage>Frage 2</frage><frage_bild/><antwort_text>Frage 2 Antwort</antwort_text><antwort_bild/></row>
</kartenset>
```

i think this part is also interesting

```
 InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
 inputSource.setEncoding("utf-8");
 inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(path));
 xr.parse(inputSource);
```

the xml parser is working when i download the same file from the web(of course with url openstream...)

i tried also:

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(cont.getResources().getAssets().open(p_uri)));
```

and different encodings.

i hope anyone can help me. thanks

**EDIT:**

I get it. now it works. no exception. the solution was this here:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
inputSource.setEncoding("utf-8");
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(p_uri));

xr.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(new File(p_uri))));
```